# DDD - Get entity through aggregate, invoke method or hide entity method behind aggegrate method?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Consider the following scenario:

```
class Order:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    def order(self, product_id, amount, price, discount=None):
        item = OrderItem(product_id, amount, price)
        self.lines.append(item)

class OrderItem:

    def __init__(self, product_id, amount, price, discount=None):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.amount = amount
        self.price = price
        self.discount = discount or decimal.Decimal(0)

    def discount(self, amount):
        self.discount = discount
```

In the scenario that we want to add a discount to a specific line item, after the `Order` aggregate has been created, do I need to get the `OrderItem` entity from the aggregate, or expose a method on the aggregate?

E.g.

```
class Order:

    ...

    def discount_item(self, index, amount):
        self.lines[index].discount(amount)
```

And if I can invoke the `OrderItem.discount()` directly -- how do I keep track of the domain events published as a result of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every change to the aggregate should be done through aggregate root's public methods. This way you can be sure the aggregate is always in the consistent state. Otherwise, you could easily break the consistency of the aggregate by modifying internal entities of the aggregates. The whole aggregate concept is about keeping all of entities and value objects inside the aggregate in valid state. So, in your case you could add a method similar to this to the `Order` aggregate root:

```
def applyDiscountForItem(self, itemPosition, amount):
    // apply the discount on item identified by itemPosition
```

If you follow this rule, the consistency of the aggregate is guaranteed. The aggregate root is the single entry point to make any changes to the aggregate, so it's quite easy to add all the business logic and validation to the root. However, when your aggregate becomes bigger, then there can be a lot of "proxy" methods in the root. If that's the case, then your aggregate probably becomes too big and needs to be split into multiple aggregates. It's generally a good idea to keep aggregate relatively small. Often, the best aggregates consist only of one entity (the aggregate root itself) and multiple value objects.